# Error using lbound/ubound depending on number of rows returned

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a bit of code that I have been using for a while to extract data from an Oracle database to Excel, but I am now getting an error with it if only 1 row is returned.  The SQL being used is fine, but I get the error "Error 9: subscript out of range" whenever a single row is returned.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub TFD()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim Query As String
Dim mtxData As Variant

' Clear the current list on Sheet7
Sheet7.Range("A2:C1000").ClearContents

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Connection string to connect to database
cn.Open ("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=XXX)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXXXX.XXX)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXX)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX")

' Request list of project and database names from database
rs.Open Sheet6.Range("TFD_SQL").Value, cn
    If rs.EOF Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With Sheet7
            col = 0
            'First Row: names of columns
            Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
                col = col + 1
            Loop
            mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
            .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData
        End With
    End If

' Close the record set
rs.Close

' Close the database connection
cn.Close

Exit Sub
```

Comment: You are getting the error at `.Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name`? Have you stepped through the code using F8 and checked `rs.Fields`? Does it still show up as an array?

Comment: I get the error at ".Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData"

Answer (score 0):

Your error "Error 9: subscript out of range" means that you are trying to access something in the array that doesn't exist. It is likely that the array mtxData has only one dimension, not two.

The line

```
.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData
```

is trying to measure the the size of both the 1st and 2nd dimension of mtxData. If mtxData has only one dimension, then `UBound(mtxData,2)` and `LBound(mtxData,2)` will both throw this error.

Below is one method to avoid getting this error...

Where your Dim statements are, add the following line:

```
Dim NumRows As Long, NumCols As Long
```

Replace this line of code:

```
.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData
```

with the following lines:

```
NumRows = 0
NumCols = 0

On Error Resume Next
NumRows = UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1
NumCols = UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1
On Error GoTo 0

If NumRows = 0 Then NumRows = 1
If NumCols = 0 Then NumCols = 1

.Range("A2").Resize(nRows, nCols) = mtxData
```

The statement `On Error Resume Next` suppresses VBA from halting when an error occurs. However, when `UBound(mtxData,2)` is an error, the value of NumCols is not calculated, and remains 0.